# Can we use Dijkstra's to find the shortest path even in a graph having negative edge weights?

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path, dijkstra

Suppose I have a graph where the minimum edge weight is −100. Can I add 100 as an offset to all the edges and use Dijkstra's algorithm?

Please help me understand why such a method gives wrong solution.

Comment: why do you think it gives wrong answers?

Comment: It gives wrong answers because Dijkstra's algorithm isn't defined for negative no's and the reason has been pointed out by Nayuki.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Adding 100 to every edge weight gives the wrong solution because it penalizes paths that have more edges than paths that have fewer edges.

For example, suppose we have a graph, and the shortest path from point A to point B has 3 edges and a total distance 5. Suppose some other path from point A to point B has 2 edges but a total distance of 10.

If we add 100 to each edge weight, then the first path has a cost of 305, while the second path has a cost of 210. So the second path becomes shorter than the first path.

[image: Example graph]

Therefore, we can conclude that adding an offset or bias to each edge weight does not necessarily preserve shortest paths.